# Restangular - How to get the request's plain results (not wrapped)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, ngresource

I am trying to get some data from a REST api using mgonto's Restangular.

```
// Restangular returns promises
Restangular.all('users').getList()  // GET: /users
.then(function(users) {
  // returns a list of users
  $scope.user = users[0]; // first Restangular obj in list: { id: 123 }
})

// Later in the code...

// Restangular objects are self-aware and know how to make their own RESTful requests
$scope.user.getList('cars');  // GET: /users/123/cars
```

That's fine, and this works, but all the results returned in the promises callbacks have some methods and properties added by Restangular (this is how you can do .getList("cars") on a user).

**What I want is to retrieve only the user's data (name, id...)** without all the Restangular methods. Just a plain JS object.

I couldn't find any way to do this in the docs. Everytime I use a method on a returned user it always returns a wrapped object with the Restangular methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are looking for 'plain()' (alias for Restangular.stripRestangular(elem)).

> plain(): Returns the plain element received from the server without
>   any of the enhanced methods from Restangular. It's an alias to calling
>   Restangular.stripRestangular(elem)

It strips all the restangular methods and returns the plain object which is returned by the server.

For more information please refer to the following link :

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods

The following fiddle might help :

`Fiddle ::`http://plnkr.co/edit/oMFnYM4HkaFK3biscpTo?p=preview

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for, but when I do requests using the promise way, I do not have the "plain" method on the returned list, nor on the objects of that list. I am using the API of the plunkr official example http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview, and when I do
Restangular.all("projects").getList().then(function(projects){projects.plain() // =>undefined method})

Comment: Did you try : .then(function(projects){Restangular.stripRestangular(projects)}) ??

Comment: Sorry to bother you again... but did you try the above mentioned approach ? :)

Comment: Hey, sorry I was on weekend. I tried it already, without success. It does strip some stuff away but not all. Have a look at it here http://plnkr.co/edit/aRSZ9X?p=preview (look at the console logs). in fact it does strip the restangular stuff from the list, but not from the objects within; even calling it on the objects themselves didn't work

Comment: I just wanted to see if it worked. I do understand the problem. It seems to be related to the following bug : https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/518 . Someone on the thread has suggested the solution that you can either copy the object on `requestInterceptor` and assign it as a property before actually getting it to the promise. I wish I could have given a better solution :\

Comment: the issue has been closed a while ago though... seems weird its not fixed yet

Comment: Yes... I didnt get any solution either :(

Comment: The only option would be to make a wrapper for "stripRestangular" and manually remove unwanted keys.. Not so nice

Comment: Is there a way to define a Restangular path to never even modify the results to begin with? Seems dumb that it adds props then removes them.

Comment: I doubt, if there is any method/interceptor provided by Restangular library not to 'restangularize' the response at all. If one doesn't need it at all, then '$http' works good too :)